# Gson - convert from Json to resourcedescriptor

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I am implementing rest webservices client to get list of reports from jasper server repository. 
I am trying to parse Jasperreports server rest web services json response to java object.  I have tried different solutions but no able to get mapped result to resouce descriptor class.  Also tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675452/gson-convert-from-json-to-list) but didn't help

Any help is appreciated.Thank you in advance.

My JSON response looks like :

```
{"resourceLookup":[{"version":0,"permissionMask":1,"creationDate":"2016-03-29T11:04:45","updateDate":"2014-05-27T18:48:25","label":"A4 Landscape","uri":"/public/templates/a4_landscape.510.jrxml","resourceType":"file"},{"version":0,"permissionMask":1,"creationDate":"2016-03-29T11:04:45","updateDate":"2014-05-27T18:48:25","label":"A4 Portrait","uri":"/public/templates/a4_portrait.510.jrxml","resourceType":"file"}]}
```

My code:

```
Type type1 = new TypeToken<List<ResourceDescriptor>>(){}.getType();
            List<ResourceDescriptor> ttt=  gson.fromJson(jasonstring, type1);
```

Error:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: try Type type1 = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<ResourceDescriptor>>>(){}.getType();

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It worked and i am able to get the data saved into map but not all the attributes of the json files mapped to resource description object. Any suggestion?